# How to find lossy parallel LC tank Q factor, bandwidth, and half-power-frequency?

Tags: capacitor, resistors, inductor, impedance, resonance

Ideal parallel LC tank has infinite impedance at resonance frequency. However, real components, especially inductors, have unignorable ESR, causing ideally infinite impedance dropping to a finite value. This also cause the LC tank resonant frequency to be lower.

Below is my calculation.

\$\omega_0\$ is resonant angular frequency. \$Z_{in0}\$ is impedance(resistance) when resonance.
[image: finding Z0 and w0]

According to my calculation, the resonant angular frequency is

$$
\omega_0 = \sqrt{ \frac{L-(R^2)\ C}{(L^2)\ C} }
$$

The resonant impedance is

$$
Z_{in0} = \frac{L}{RC}
$$

According to my simulation, the result seems correct.

I use 1 V AC signal. The "I(V1)" is current provide by the voltage source.
There is 180° phase shift because the current is measured from voltage source positive to negative (from LC tank to voltage source).

$$
\mathrm{R = 40 \Omega , \  L = 10 \ mH , \  C = 100 \ nF. \\
\omega_0 = 31.369\ krad/s \Rightarrow f_0 = 4.992 kHz\\
R0 = 2.5 \ k\Omega }
$$

[image: simulation]
I use these values because I have these components. Maybe I will do the experiment in real circuit.

My question is, how to find out the Q factor, bandwidth, and half-power frequency of the circuit? I have tried to calculate by myself, but it ended up I have no idea what to do next.
[image: finding w1 and w2]
Is it possible to find half-power angular frequency from the crazy equetion? Or I have made some mistake in some steps?

Comment: Go [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RLC_circuit#Other_configurations) at this subsection.

Comment: @periblepsis I have ready read this. At first I didn't know that Q factor of the inductor is Q factor of the whole circuit.  Thanks to Andy aka telling me that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *My question is, how to find out the Q factor, bandwidth, and
> half-power frequency of the circuit?*

For your tuned circuit (with inductive ESR), the Q factor of the whole circuit is exactly the same as the Q factor for the lossy inductor. In other words, the Q factor of the circuit is defined by the Q factor of the lossy inductor: -

$$Q = \dfrac{\omega L}{R_{ESR}}$$

For \$\omega\$, you use the natural resonant frequency: \$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{LC}}\$

If you think about what your circuit looks like "stand alone", all three components (R, L and C) are in series so, you treat the relationship as you would with a series tuned circuit for Q factor. Extract from [wiki RLC circuits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_factor#RLC_circuits): -

[image]

---

Given that the Q factor equals resonant frequency divided by bandwidth, you can calculate upper and lower 3 dB points. This is also covered on the same wiki page linked to above: -

[image]

Comment: Just one comment (for clarification): It is correct that the Q-factor of the circuit is identical to the Q-factor of the inductor - to be clear: This is the pole-Q (Qp). With other words, it the quality factor of the pole (left part of the s-plane). However, the Qp is identical to the relative bandwidth (Q=wo/delta w) for a parallel loss-resistor only. This is because only in in such a case the numerator of the circuits function is pure imaginary  (bandpass function).

Comment: Thank you very much. According to wiki, seem like Q = w0*L/R, not Q = 2pi*w0*L/R? And could you please briefly explain why w0 = 1/sqrt(LC) ? I see this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RLC_circuit#Other_configurations here. The real resonance frequency is not the natural resonant frequency. Or this is the definition?

Comment: @WillisLin (1) \$2\pi f\$ is equal to \$\omega\$. (2) \$2\pi\omega\$ is meaningless. (3) There are several definitions of resonant frequency and, one of them (the natural undamped resonant frequency) is \$\frac{1}{\sqrt{LC}}\$. (4) I think you have calculated the frequency where impedance is at a maximum and that is slightly different to the natural resonant frequency. (5) Or, you could have calculated the frequency at which the input impedance is purely resistive. All of them are close in a fairly resonant (high-Q) tuned circuit.

Comment: @Andy aka (1) I know 2pi*f = w. (2) I mean, seems like you mistyped 2pi*w in your above answer, at first equation :) (3) I got it. (4)(5) The impedance I calculated was the purely resistive impedance.

Comment: @WillisLin oops so I did. I thought you were talking about the wiki quote. On its way to being fixed. Thanks.

Comment: I think, there is only one - commonly agreed - definition for resonance: Imaginary part of the transfer function resp. of the input impedance equal to zero (zero phase shift).  In many cases, this is the frequency where the magnitude reaches its maximum - but not always and not for each and every circuit.

Comment: @LvW well, it's either the undamped natural frequency (I think you also refer to that as the pole frequency), peak magnitude frequency or, resistive input frequency. I don't mind calling any of them resonance!!

Comment: Quote: "I don't mind calling any of them resonance!!"  So - am I wrong with my claim that there would be only one - commonly used - definition for resonance?

Comment: I can't say your wrong but neither can I say you're right @LvW

Comment: For a 2nd order LPF many will say that resonance in the TF is when there is 90 degrees of phase shift. And, for a 2nd order LPF (as described by the OP) maximum output peak does not occur at the pure resistive input impedance point.  The pure resistive input impedance point would be another contender.

Comment: Maybe that "many will say" - but they are wrong. I do not hesitate to claim that there is not one single book or (serious) internet article which will support such a "definition". To make it clear - I only speak about resonance effects in electronic circuits.

Answer (score 1):

When driven with an ideal current source, the shown circuit resembles the **superposition of a 2nd-order lowpass and a 2nd-order bandpass**. Both functions have the same denominator and, thus, the same pole position. This is confirmed by evaluating the circuits transfer function

**Z(s)=(R+sL)/(1+sRC+s²LC)=N(s)/(1 + s/wpQp + s²/wp²)**.

Therefore, we cannot automatically apply the formalism which applies for an ideal bandpass (tank) circuit. For demonstrating the particular properties of the circuit I have simulated and calculated some typical parameters for **two different loss resistors** :

**1) R=40 Ohm** : **fmax=5.03kHz; fp=5.03kHz; fo=4.99kHz; B=0.636 kHz; Qc=Qp=Q=7.91**

**2) R=200 Ohm**: **fmax=4.89kHz; fp=5.03kHz; **fo**=3.89kHz; **B**=3.2kHz; **Qc=Qp=Q**=1.58**

**Explanation:**

**fmax**=f for max amplitude; **fp**=pole frequency from Z(s); **fo**=f for zero phase (resonance frequency);
**B**=3dB bandwidth; **Qp** (pole Q from Z(s)); **Qc**=fmax/B;

**Evaluation:**

**1.)**  The difference between fmax and the pole frequency fp becomes visible for the larger loss resistor only. This shows the influence of the lowpass function on the bandpass response.

**2.)** In principle, this applies also to the resonance frequency fo. This frequency is smaller than fmax and fp - however, a remarkable difference can be observed for R=200 Ohm only.

**3.)** As expected, there is a remarkable difference in bandwidth B between both cases - and the same applies to the quality factor Q. It is, however, interesting to note that in both cases, the circuits Q-value equals with sufficient accuracy the pole-Q (Qp) which can be derived from the transfer function very easily.

**4.)** Hence, to find the circuits bandwidth B it is **not necessary** to calculate the **3-dB points** from the transfer function. The bandwidth can be calculated using the pole-Q and the pole frequency fp from the transfer function: **B=fp/Qp**

**Comment**: For R=40 Ohm the difference in magnitude ("dynamic") between 0 Hz and fmax is app. 36 dB. For R=200 Ohm this dynamic is reduced to 10 dB and for R=400 Ohm it is only 0.5dB.

That means: Only for small values for the loss resistor R the circuit can be regarded as a bandpass (dynamic more than app. 30dB). For larger R values the lowpass influence gets larger and larger - and the circuit looses its bandpass character.